# Implement VAR model in R with HAC corrected standard errors

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity, vector-autoregression, robust-standard-error

I have fitted a VAR model in R (with function VAR) and would like to use HAC corrected standard errors. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Given that VARs are simply estimated via equation-by-equation OLS, you could fit each equation by `lm` and then obtain HAC standard errors from the `sandwich` package.

Example:

```
library(sandwich)

n <- 100
y1 <- arima.sim(list(ar=0.5), n)
y2 <- arima.sim(list(ar=0.7), n) # so, not really a VAR but two independent AR(1) processes, just for simplicity

eq1 <- lm(y1[2:n]~y1[1:(n-1)]+y2[1:(n-1)])
eq1 <- lm(y2[2:n]~y1[1:(n-1)]+y2[1:(n-1)])

vcovHAC(eq1)
```

It may also be worth contemplating *why* you aim to use HAC standard errors. If your goal is to capture serial correlation in the errors, a more natural strategy would seem to include higher lags in the VAR model.

Comment: Many Thanks Christoph. What about the impulse response function? I can only present it via a VAR-object and this workaround would not provide me with such an object. Do you think robust standard errors are more suitable than HAC-errors?

Comment: Two questions here: for the point estimates of the IRF, you can still use the standard var package as these are not related to the s.e.s. For error bands, I would suggest a bootstrap that also deals with heteroskedasticity (as I mentioned, if you still encounter serial correlation I suggest adding more lags to the VAR).

Comment: 2nd: "Do you think robust standard errors are more suitable than HAC-errors?" HAC s.e.s *are* a type of robust s.e.s, also being robust to serial correlation and not just heteroskedasticity. But as I said, s.e.s only robust to heteroskedasticity seem more sensible in a VAR, as remaining serial correlation should, in my view, be captured through extra lags in the VAR.